# Understanding JavaScript Closures - Freeze variable passed to callback

Tags: javascript, closures

I do not yet have a basic understanding of JavaScript closures;

I have a question regarding a specific situation that perhaps is also basic and common example:

**Count from 1 to 3 in 3 seconds**

See JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/nAh8x/

The code:

```
var i,
    t;

t = 0;

// Case A

for( i=1; i<=3; i++ ) {
    setTimeout( function() { log(i); }, t );
    t += 1000;
}

// Case B

for( i=1; i<=3; i++ ) {
    setTimeout( wrapper(i), t );
    t += 1000;
}

function wrapper(i) {
    return function() { log(i); };
}

// Log utility function

function log(msg) {
    $('#log').append( msg + '<br />' );
}
```

Case **A** doesn't work.

It's clear to me why: every time the function inside **setTimeout** is called and accesses the **i** variable, its value has already reached 4.

Case **B** works.

When **wrapper(i)** is called it returns

```
function() { log(i); };
```

and the above return value (a function) is what goes inside setTimeout. What goes inside setTimeout is exactly the same as Case **A**

But this time, the **i** variable have been "frozen" with the value at the time of the call.

Why using the **wrapper** function let the passed value to be frozen?

That's not completely clear to me.

Comment: Paulo, I don't wish to be unkind but your opening statement needs amending. It should read, "I *do not yet* have a basic understanding of JavaScript closures". What you are struggling with is the basic concept, namely that a closure traps its local variables and continues to allow inner function(s) access to such variables and free variables even after the outer function has completed and returned. For this to happen a persistent reference to the inner function(s) must exist, eg by assignment of a returned function.

Comment: Paulo, OK maybe I was slightly unkind but you took it on the chin - good for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wrapper function has it's own `i` that is locally scoped to it.

This receives the **value** of the other `i` at the time `wrapper` is called.

It might be clearer if you rewrote it as:

```
function wrapper(notI) {
    return function() { log(notI); };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Closure is an environment which is created with variables scope and nested function by calling of outer function,

Every time the `wrapper()` is called there would created each different environment for below's function

```
function wrapper(i) {
    return function() { log(i); };
}
```

Here is the `i`'s value would be same as when `wrapper()` is invoked. Each time the `i`'s value would be private for that particular environment which made by invoking `wrapper()` outer function.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `i` used inside `wrapper` is the one the has been passed (as a *copy*) as the formal parameter to `wrapper`.  It's not the same `i` as the one inside your `for` loop - you could rename that variable to anything you like and the code would still work.

It's frozen because it has the value it had each time `wrapper` was originally called.