# Javascirpt: How to pass JSON response as parameter from onreadystatechange?

Tags: javascript, html, json, onclick

So I'm trying to get a list of JSON objects and then loop through its elements via fori loop, creating `<li>` and `<a>` elements.
Everything works smoothly except when I try to add an onclick function to the  in each iteration. I'm trying to pass the json object to the onclick function, but all  tags have are showing the **last** json object.

What I need is for every `<a>` to show its corresponding json object when clicked.

Please see the code:

```
var url = "https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all"

var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var countries = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText)

    var ul = document.getElementById('countries')

    for (var i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) { //start iteration

      var li = document.createElement("LI")
      var img = document.createElement("IMG")
      var a = document.createElement("A")
      var textNode = document.createTextNode(countries[i].name)

      img.setAttribute("src", countries[i].flag)
      ul.appendChild(li)
      li.appendChild(a)
      a.appendChild(img)
      a.appendChild(textNode);
      a.setAttribute("title", countries[i].name)

      var country = countries[i]
      a.onclick = function(){ CountryClicked(country)} //pass the current JSON to the onclick function of the current <a> Node, this isn't working correctly.
    }

  }
}

xhttp.open('GET', url, true);
xhttp.send();


function CountryClicked(country){
  var div = document.getElementById("parent-country-container")
  var h1 = document.createElement("h1")
  // div.appendChild(h1)
  h1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(country.name + " Clicked"))
  div.innerHTML = ""
  div.appendChild(h1)
}
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Just bind it to the click event: `a.onclick = function(country){CountryClicked(country)}.bind(a, countries[i])`. The `country` you defined as var is declared for the whole function scope and therefore holds the value of the last assignment made in the loop.

Comment: On your bind event click you need to use a closures function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is neccesary to use a closures function to be able to send the right country.

```js
function CountryClicked(el) {
  alert(el.name);
}

var countries = [{'flag':'xx',name:'name'}, {'flag':'xx',name:'text 2'}];
    var ul = document.getElementById('countries')
    for (var i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) { //start iteration
      var li = document.createElement("LI")
      var img = document.createElement("IMG")
      var a = document.createElement("A")
      var textNode = document.createTextNode(countries[i].name)

      img.setAttribute("src", countries[i].flag)
      ul.appendChild(li)
      li.appendChild(a)
      a.appendChild(img)
      a.appendChild(textNode);
      a.setAttribute("title", countries[i].name)

      var country = countries[i];
      a.onclick = (function(country){ 
        return function(){ CountryClicked(country); }
     })(country); 
    }
```

```html
<ul id="countries"></ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me out in the right direction.

But can you please explain why I need to use closure and it wouldn't work as an function call normally?

Comment: You welcome @Ryuga Law. In a normal function call paramters are passed by value and in a closures  parameters are  passed by reference (pointer to memory address). It is another post here that explain with examples closures and freeze variable. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21363295/understanding-javascript-closures-freeze-variable-passed-to-callback